# htaccess override requested uri exists in cache folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to check if user request any page, htaccess check that page in cache folder and if cached page exist. htaccess rewrite it requested page to that cached page.

folder structure:

root/
       product/
       services/
       cache/
              product/index.html
              services/index.html
       index.php
       images/
       css/

eg: example.com/product/ to example.com/cache/product/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$2/index.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$1/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$1 [L]
```

Comment: if I type example.com/product/ its saying not found 404, example.com/product/index.html than its working. please help me in it

Comment: I will use this script for dynamic files like minifyied js css

Comment: Make sure this .htaccess is in `DocumentRoot` and this rule is your very first rule. Also make sure `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/cache/product/index.html` file exists.

Comment: the file is there. and .htaccess is in root dir

Comment: I managed the your code. thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: Your answer is actually derived directly from my answer and in all fairness you should mark my answer as accepted. btw I have updated my answer with your suggested one.

Comment: Very, very neat use of mod-rewrite! +1 both to the question and the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81 for your kind words. Yes this turned out to be pretty complex logic and it seems OP is still facing some issue as evident from other thread with extra long comments section :-)

Comment: @anubhava Saving this link, this is a cool idea and solution that deserves to be known. :)